# Flutter: Icon works locally but fails android driver test: Error: Member not found: 'airline_stops'

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, flutter-test

I'm trying to use the icon "Icons.airline_stops" that can be found on the flutter website https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/airline_stops-constant.html

When I compile it on my local emulator, it displays correctly as I want. However, when I do a commit and the android drive test are run, it fails.

- drive_android (Failed)
- drive_ios (Success)

Problematic line in the error:

```
lib/external_projects/project1/screens/finish_experiment.dart:71:23: Error: Member not found: 'airline_stops'.
                Icons.airline_stops,
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I change this icon to another one, the android drive test passes successfully. But I'd like to use this one and since it's in the flutter.dev website it should work...

Complete error log:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...                   WARNING | /etc/localtime does not point to zoneinfo-compatible timezone name
    5.4s
Running "flutter pub get" in my_project...                       36.4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                          
[flutter_background_geolocation] Purging debug resources in release build
lib/external_projects/project1/screens/finish_experiment.dart:71:23: Error: Member not found: 'airline_stops'.
                Icons.airline_stops,
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/flutter/2.8.1-stable/x64/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1070

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/flutter/2.8.1-stable/x64/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 18s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            140.9s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Error: The process '/bin/sh' failed with exit code 1
Terminate Emulator
INFO    | Discarding the changed state: command-line flag
WARNING | Discarding the changed state (command-line flag).
INFO    | Shutting down gRPC endpoint
INFO    | Shutting down gRPC endpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

The virtual machine flutter version used to run drive_android tests has to be updated to match the flutter version.

**Explanation:**

In this case, my flutter versions were as follows:

- Local device: Flutter 2.10.5
- drive_android: Flutter 2.8.1
- drive_ios: Flutter 2.10.0

The icon Icon.airline_stops was probably introduced in a flutter version older than 2.8.1, that's the reason why it failed drive_android but passed both the local device (that is using Android) and the drive_ios tests.

Therefore, to solve this all versions must be updated to match the local device. And, why not update drive_ios too to avoid something similar happening in the future?

- Local device: Flutter 2.10.5
- drive_android: Flutter 2.8.1 -> 2.10.5
- drive_ios: Flutter 2.10.0 -> 2.10.5